# Using Freenas 11.2 my java process closes when leaving jail shell

Tags: java, unix, post, boot

For the past 2 weeks I've been busy trying to figure out how to setup my minecraft server onto my freenas server.

I was able to get it up and running stably when going into the jail manually typing in my startup command:

> cd /root/Minecraft_Server
>
> java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.4.2757-universal.jar

And then just close the shell.

I tried looking to automate this command and put it into and sh file in crontab and everything, that didn't work so i decided to upgrade to 11.2 to see if that has any solutions.

Now the main problem already is that if I try to run my command manually in the shell, and i leave the webui, it will just close the server down to unlike in the 11.1 freenas.

Does anyone have any more ideas here?

In the same location as the server I have a minecraft.sh script with this command.
If I manually run the script it works, but if I use crontab it won't start it either.
The corntab command that i've used is:

> @reboot /root/Minecraft_Server/minecraft.sh

I also tried putting in the command directly but this also was useless.

I even tried the exec.poststart but when i direct it to /root/minecraft_Server/minecraft.sh it won't start either, it won't even run the jail anymore

Answer (score 0):

use “screen java ...”
on relog to shell do screen -x to get on the server shell

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Java command as a service that starts whenever the jail starts. That way, the Java server doesn’t depend on the shell or webui.

Basically, create a `usr/local/etc/rc.d/minecraftd` file that includes the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# PROVIDE: minecraftd
# REQUIRE: LOGIN DAEMON NETWORKING mountcritlocal
# KEYWORD: shutdown
#
# Use the following variables to configure the minecraft server. For example, to
# configure the ON/OFF knob variable:
# sysrc minecraftd_enable="YES"
#
# minecraftd_enable="YES"
# minecraftd_user_dir="/root/minecraft"
# minecraftd_jar_path="/root/minecraft/server.jar"
# minecraftd_java_opts="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"

. /etc/rc.subr

name=minecraftd
rcvar=`set_rcvar`
pidfile=/var/run/minecraftd.pid

load_rc_config $name

start_cmd="${name}_start"

: ${minecraftd_enable="NO"}
: ${minecraftd_user_dir="/root/minecraft"}
: ${minecraftd_jar_path="/root/minecraft/server.jar"}
: ${minecraftd_java_opts="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M"}

minecraftd_start() {
    if [ -e $pidfile ]; then
        echo "$name already running."
    else
        echo "Starting $name..."
        /usr/sbin/daemon -f -p $pidfile \
            /usr/local/bin/java -Duser.dir=$minecraftd_user_dir \
            $minecraftd_java_opts \
            -jar $minecraftd_jar_path nogui
        echo "$name started."
    fi
}

run_rc_command $1
```

Then configure the service to start on boot:

```
sysrc minecraftd_enable="YES"
```

And restart your jail.

For more information, check [Installing a Minecraft server on FreeNAS](https://devpro.media/minecraft-server-freenas/#connecting-a-minecraft-client).

Disclaimer: My team published that article.

Hope this helps somebody.